# Can you make a global rule that `virtual` properties are automatically nullable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, episerver, nullable-reference-types

With how the `virtual` keyword interacts with EPiServer CMS's implementation of `EntityFramework`, where empty properties will be read as `null`, is there a way to define at a project-level that all `virtual` properties *are* nullable?

These properties are inherently & quietly nullable in any case, and we need to directly check if these properties are `null` or not when working on them in EPiServer projects. As I understand it, it makes more sense to designate that `virtual` implicitly means that the property is nullable than to have every single property on any CMS Page, Block, Media asset (image, video, audio, file) explicitly add `?` to give that context & clarity.

The Null-state analysis itself is desired, however due to the overall quantity of properties that would need to be individually denoted as nullable, some way to effectively bulk-define propeties as nullable would be ideal.

Comment: I wouldn't. There may be cases where you want a virtual property to be non-nullable, and inherited properties such as `Name` shouldn't be nullable as they're required core property types. Also, changing language characteristics on a per-project basis can be really confusing to developers.

Comment: Specific to the use-case in mind, the goal is more or less having a way to let us cleanly go "hey, any of these properties *will* end up reading as null if the editor has not defined a value". I do agree modifying how `virtual` works is a bad idea, and I feel I phrased my ask poorly in that regard. The main ask was to try & find a way to bulk-define properties as `nullable` to more cleanly work with the data as we are receiving it.

Comment: It appears that we are going to be going the route of adding the `?` to every property we are creating that is `virtual` & coming through the `EPiServer` Database implementation (where they all *are* `null` when not populated by the user/editor)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, but you can simply disable Null-state analysis for the code or whole project. [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)

Comment: With the use-case in question, I am seeking to keep Null-state analysis. Ideally, having some way to bulk-define properties as nullable would be preferable in this use-case, so that you do not have to add the `?` denotation to hundreds our thousands of properties across a project.